# Parse XSD file to get element names from complex type

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd

I am trying to get the element names in an XSD file. Let's say I have this xsd:

```
<xsd:complexType name="SomethingOne">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Id" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:element name="Time" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Location" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Building" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Comments" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="SomethingTwo">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Id" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:element name="Time" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Location" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Building" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Phone" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Device" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Protocol" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Comments" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

For `SomethingOne`, I want to print out all the element names (e.g. `Id`, `Time`, `Location`, etc...). Here's the Java code I have:

```
public void parse(String id) {
    try {
        // Setup classes to parse XSD file for complex types
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream("filepath.xsd"));

        // Given the id, go to correct place in XSD to get all the parameters
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList result = (NodeList) xpath.compile(getExpression(id)).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for(int i = 0; i < result.getLength(); i++) 
        {
            Element e = (Element) result.item(i);
            System.out.println(e.getAttribute("name") + " = " + e.getNodeValue());
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Get XSD Expression
private String getExpression(String id) {
    String expression = "";

    switch(id)
    {
    case "99":
        expression = "//xsd:complexType[@name='SomethingOne']//xsd:element";
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("\n Invalid id");
        break;
    }

    return expression;
}
```

The problem I'm having is the `for` loop. `result.getLength()` returns `0`. I cannot figure out why. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your xsd valid? I tested the expression online and it worked, but only with a small workarounds in your xsd.

I just put the code inside a xsd:schema tag:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:complexType name="SomethingOne">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Id" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:element name="Time" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Location" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Building" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Comments" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="SomethingTwo">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Id" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:element name="Time" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Location" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Building" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Phone" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Device" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Protocol" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Comments" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The xpath query seems to be ok with these changes. Tested here: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

---

**UPDATE:**

Remove "xsd:" in the xpath query:

```
//complexType[@name='SomethingOne']//element
```

I tested it in a Java project and returned 5 results.

Comment: It should be valid (it has a `xsd:schema` tag on top), as the company I work for has been using it for a while. I'm not allowed to change the xsd file. So I can't replace all the `xsd:` with `xs:`. Is there no way for this work with `xsd:`?

Comment: I just checked, and yes. It seems to work with xsd: (I edited the answer). Are you sure the xsd:schema tag is correct?

Comment: Just tested it with the schema tag I have on that website and it works. There must be something wrong with my Java code. Though, I can't see what it could be.

Comment: Just edited the answer. Check it. The xsd: reference is not needed in the xpath query.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great now. How did you figure it out?

Comment: I already expected that it should be related to the schema, so I tried a couple of changes, and that one worked.

Comment: Sir, can you tell me how to get both element as well as attribute? How should be the expression? At present I am keeping two expressions - one for element and one for attribute. But it will be better if I use combined expression. Example: 1) <xs:attribute name="Bby" type="ActiveOrInActiveCode" use="required"/> 2) <xs:element name="MainHeader" type="MainHeader1"/>